# input command with System.out.format in while loop

Tags: java

i wrote this simple java program but output is not correct.
i find out that if i use System.out.println instead of System.out.format the problem solved .
but i want to use System.out.format in while loop and understand why this happened?
this program give members of an array from user and sort theme.
(my IDE is netbeans 11.3 in linux)

```
package array_example2;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main { 
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Array length : ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int[] x = new int[n];              
    int i=0;
    while (i<n)
    {            
        System.out.format("Enter Array member %d",i);
        x[i] = input.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
    MySort.mysort(x);
    System.out.format("Array x = %s", Arrays.toString(x));        
}
```

MySort class :

```
package array_example2;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MySort {
public static void mysort(int...a){
    Arrays.sort(a);

}
```

output :

```
Enter Array length : 
3
67
89
23
Enter Array member 0Enter Array member 1Enter Array member 2Array x = [23, 67, 89]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 24s
```

Comment: Are you asking why it's all on one line?

Comment: @user use `%n`, rather than `\n`, as it is platform-independent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\n` or `%n` to indicate a new line at the end of the string. System.out.format doesn't create a new line like System.out.println does.

```
System.out.format("Array x = %s%n", Arrays.toString(x));
```

Comment: you mean put \n in : System.out.format("Enter Array member %d\n",i); yes this is true thanks

Comment: @Alien_xxx Either the conversion or the escape character would work. As AndyTurner mentioned, it's a better idea to use `%n` because that is platform-independent.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, for the `System.format` method call, you need to add a new line, using the %n to trigger the scanner for more input.:

```
while (i < n) {
    System.out.format("Enter Array member %d%n", i+1);
    x[i++] = input.nextInt();
}
```